# How to interpret (call/cc call/cc)?

Tags: callcc

I'm familiar with using `call/cc` to interpret CPS programs in a direct style:

```lisp
(define (f return)                                                                                                                               
  (return 2)                                                                                                                                     
  3)

(f (lambda (x) x))
=> 3

(call/cc f)
=> 2
```

I'm also familiar with how `(call/cc call/cc)` behaves, with `((call/cc call/cc) x)` being equivalent to `(x x)`:

```lisp
((call/cc call/cc) display)
=> #<procedure #2 display>
```

The outer `call/cc` calls the argument `call/cc` with `f` that represents a continuation

```lisp
(★ display)
```

But what continuation does the inner `call/cc` pass to `f`, considering that it wasn't called at a source location and was called as "part of a higher-order function"/"a value"?

If it's treated as being evaluated at the source location, intuition tells me it'll reduce similarly to:

```lisp
((¹call/cc ²call/cc) display)
(²call/cc ¹(★ display))
(²((¹call/cc ★) display) display)
((¹call/cc display) display)
(display ¹(★ display))
```

which does not match the behavior `(display display)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're being a bit misled by the Wikipedia page because it only explains continuations by examples, which are too limited to cover your question.

*Every* expression has a continuation representing *everything that happens afterward*.  Conventionally we write

E[ expr ] c

to say "the meaning of expr with continuation c". Scheme implements a set of rules concerning such meanings. For example

E[ (+ A B) ] c = E[A] lambda (a) E[B] lambda (b) (c (+ a b))

The meaning of the Scheme addition of A and B is the meaning of A with a continuation that accepts that value and finds the meaning of B with a continuation that accepts that value, adds both values, and calls the continuation with the result as a parameter.

Okay. Now we're ready for the definition of call/cc:

E[ (call/cc F) ] c = E[ (F c) ] c

That is, the meaning of (call/cc f) with continuation c is the just the meaning of f applied to c with unchanged continuation. I think this answers your question: the continuation isn't altered by call/cc. It's just "exposed" as a parameter.

(This rule actually leaves stuff out for simplicity. Finding the meaning of F before it's called should be spelled out.)

So let's look at the case (call/cc call/cc):

E[ (call/cc call/cc) ] c
= E[ (call/cc c) ] c
= E[ (c c) ] c

That is, the meaning of (call/cc call/cc) is the continuation of this expression applied to itself.

For example, suppose we have ((call/cc call/cc) foo). The continuation here is (lambda (c) (c foo)) (as in the Wikipedia page). So the result will be:

((lambda (c) (c foo)) (lambda (c) (c foo)))
=> ((lambda (c) (c foo)) foo)
=> (foo foo)

So if foo is the identity, then so is the overall meaning of the expression.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: What property prevents `c` from being applied twice? I.e., why isn't it that `E[ (c c) ] c` ⇒ `(c (c c))`? That is, what rule am I missing conceptually here that lets both `(display (call/cc (lambda (x) 2)))` and `(display (call/cc (lambda (x) (x 2))))` result in displaying `2`, rather than the latter displaying `2#!void`?

Comment: In the first one, `x` is bound to a continuation but ignored, so the result is 2. In the second, the continuation captured at the call/cc is applied to 2.  That continuation is `(lambda (x) (display x))` or - more simply - `display`. So again, you get the 2 displayed.  If you want to think about it operationally, calling the continuation works like a "goto" that unwinds execution to the site of the call/cc, acting as though the argument passed to the continuation is being returned. But, operational thinking doesn't help much when reasoning about (call/cc call/cc).

Comment: I'm still confused about why `E[ (c x) ] c` ⇒ `(c x)` rather than `(c (c x))`. In the first expression, the continuation is `c`, right? Why/in what cases (esp if multiple continuations are involved) is the continuation of an expression "changed" / not executed? Is there a "special" evaluation case `E[ (c ...) ] c` ⇒ `(c ...)`? How does it work then when `c` is used as part of a sub-expression `E[ (+ 1 (c ...)) ] c`?

Comment: Yeah. Continuation representation of programs is inside-out. I think you may be mixing the function that is the program with continuations. `E[ ] c` acts like a "compiler" that builds a function (which isn't a continuation itself) by composing functionality onto the existing continuation `c`, which in turn is "the rest of the program."  The meaning of an entire program is the function `E[ program ] lambda x.x`.  I.e. the meaning of the expression for the whole program with an identity continuation.  (Or you can wrap a call to this in a display function, which you seem to be doing.)

Comment: Also I may be responsible for confusing you by skipping details for simplicity. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, I see. So when a continuation is applied as part of a program, the "remainder" continuation becomes identity.

Comment: It is if the calll/cc is being made at top level. If the call/cc is deeper in the program, it will be the rest of the computation afterward.